# Do real-world algorithms that greatly outperform in the class below exist?

Tags: algorithms, big-o

Last night I was discussing with another programmer that even though something may be O(1), an operation which is O(n) may outperform it if there are is a large constant in the O(1) algorithm. He disagreed, so I've brought it here.

Are there examples of algorithms which greatly outperform those in the class below it? For example, O(n) being faster than O(1) or O(n<sup>2</sup>) being faster than O(n).

Mathematically this can be demonstrated for a function with an asymptotic upper bounds, when you disregard constant factors, but do such algorithms exist in the wild? And where would I find examples of them? What types of situations are they used for?

Comment: Even for "big" algorithms, smaller is not necessarily better. For example, gaussian elimination is O(n^3), but there are algorithms that can do it in O(n^2), but the coefficient for the quadratic time algo is so huge that people just go with the O(n^3) one.

Comment: @BlackJack Thanks, this is exactly the type of example I am looking for. Kindly, put it in the answers and reap the points!

Comment: You have to add "... for real-world problems" or some such to make this a sensible question. Otherwise you only need to make `n` big enough to compensate for the constant (which is the point of big-O notation).

Comment: @starblue "but do such algorithms exist in the wild?" To me restricts the question to real-world algorithms and examples.

Comment: Take any O(f(n)) algorithm. If you put a bound on n, it becomes O(1), which does not make it any faster.

Comment: Don't take big-O notation for speed.

Comment: The point of big-O notation is not to tell you how fast an algorithm runs, but how well it scales.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has mentioned the Simplex algorithm for solving LP. It has an exponential worst-case with a linear expected run-time. In practice, it is quite fast. It's trivial to construct a problem that exhibits the worst-case run-time as well. Also, it's heavily used.

Comment: related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/77529/why-isnt-radix-sort-used-more-often

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Lookups in very small, fixed data tables.  An optimized hash table may be O(1) and yet slower than a binary search or even a linear search due to the cost of the hash calculation.

Comment: More precisely, hashtable lookup is O(m) where m is the size of the key. You only get to call that O(1) if the key size is constant. Also, usually that's amortized - otherwise the table can't grow/shrink. Ternary trees can often beat hash tables for string lookups in contexts where the strings quite often aren't found - the ternary tree search will often discover that the key isn't present while still checking the first character or two of the string, where the hashtable version hasn't yet calculated the hash.

Comment: I should have said - by the same argument, a ternary tree search is O(m log n) unless the size of the key is constant. There's no asymptotic advantage to the ternary tree - the log n is a clear disadvantage - but there's a common (probability-based) constants advantage.

Comment: I love Loren Pechtel's answer and Steve314's first comment. I've actually seen this happen. If you create a Java class that has a hashcode() method that takes too long to return the hash value (and doesn't/can't cache it), then using instances of such a class in a hash-type collection (like HashSet) will make that collection ALOT slower than an array-type collection (like ArrayList).

Comment: @Steve314: why do you assume hash functions are O(m) where m is the size of the key? Hash functions can be O(1) even if you are dealing with strings (or other complex type). There is no too much value to put it in formal definition than simply realizing the hash function could significantly change the complexity if a wrong data structure (hash table) is chosen for your input (key size is unpredictable).

Comment: @Steve314: Note that I said fixed data tables.  They don't grow.  Also, you only get O(1) performance from a hash table if you can optimize the key to ensure there are no collisions.

Comment: @Loren - strictly, if the table has a fixed size, there's a constant maximum amount of time you can spend looking for an free space. That is, at most, you can need to check n-1 already-filled slots where n is the constant table size. So a fixed-size hash table really is O(1), without needing amortized analysis. This doesn't mean you don't care about the accesses getting slower as the table fills - only that it isn't what big O expresses.

Comment: @Loren - actually, there's a bit of a cheat in the amortized claim of O(1) with hashtables that isn't often stated. The size of the hash defines the maximum table-size that can be handled efficiently without collisions. Above that size, the performance degrades to that of the collision-handling mechanism - typically O(n) for chaining lists. This *could* be relevant right now, with forgotten 32-bit hash calculations still being used in tables that have grown to require 64-bit address spaces.

Comment: @Codism - a hash function calculated from a string is calculated from *all* the characters of the string. If the string has m characters, the hash calculation has m steps and takes O(m) time. The same principle applies to big integers and other variable-sized types. There are tricks that can be used to avoid that, like using the address of an interned string as the hash, but that implies *other* performance issues - like the data structure used for the interning. You can also cache the hashes, but you still have to calculate them once, plus you need to store that with every copy of the string.

Comment: @Steve314: how about return s[0]+s[s.length-1]? What disqualifies it not a hash function for string?

Comment: @Codism - because it isn't a function of the whole string. It's in the realm of the "tricks that can be used to avoid that" that I already mentioned as having other performance problems - in this case lots of hash collisions. If you know in advance that these collisions reliably don't occur, then you know something special about those keys - something that implies the *true* key is only the first and last letters anyway, since only they are relevant to the lookup.

Comment: @Steve314: who says a string hash function has to take all characters in a string into calculation? Depending on the probability model of the problem domain, a "partial" hash does not necessarily mean more hash collisions. In most cases, a dedicated "partial" hash works equally good enough compared to a "full" hash.

Comment: @Codism - I already answered that. Since your lookup only really cares about the first and last characters (or else you'd get lots of hash collisions), your key is really only the first and last characters. The extreme case is when your hash function simply returns some constant value such as zero. If this works without causing lots of collisions, you don't need key-based lookup at all - the *real* key is non-existent. If you have no collisions at all, you can only be storing at most one item. If you have tolerable numbers of hash collisions, your hashtable is just an overcomplex linked list.

Comment: @Codism - I don't deny that it's valid as a convenient trick for special cases, but it *is* a special-case trick and shouldn't be misrepresented as an appropriate normal-case method. It's basic textbook stuff that the hash function should be based on the whole key and should assign hash values in an "unpredictable" way - basically meaning pseudo-randomly using the key as the seed. Anything else is special-case trick. The "hash" isn't really a hash any more (it's just some arbitrary function of the key), or else the real key is only a part of what it appears to be, or whatever.

Comment: @Codism - of course there's enough out there that defines "hash function" as any function that maps a wider range of values to a smaller one - I disagree with that definition, and I've seen textbooks that agree with me, but at this point the whole argument boils down to pedantry about word definitions - and I guess you can probably find textbooks that contradict my "basic textbook stuff" claim. IOW we should agree to disagree.

Comment: @Steve314: You're talking about *cryptographic* hashing.  But you don't need crypto-strength hashes to make a proper hash table.  You just need a *relatively* low frequency of collisions (along with basic properties like immutability and reproducibility).

Comment: @Kevin - I just read all those comments I wrote 4 years ago and I don't see anything to do with cryptographic hashing. Hashing a whole string is O(n) because there are n characters to hash - the string length varies. If you only hash a constant part of the string, sure that would be a problem for a cryptographic hash, but it's also potentially a problem for a hashtable. Codism suggested a hash calculated as `s[0]+s[s.length-1]` - for 8-bit characters that's a grand total of 512 unique keys (and a non-flat distribution) even ignoring the fact some characters are more common than others.

Comment: @Kevin - that means you probably get lots of hash collisions even with a very small number of strings, and above 512 keys **every single** new key is a collision. And that means the asymptotic performance degrades to the performance of the collision handling - usually O(n) where n is the number of keys.

Comment: @Steve314: I'm not advocating that particular algorithm.  Actually, IMHO, you should be hashing and interning your strings at construction time, which is already O(n) anyway.  Then your hash table really is O(1), by virtue of all the expensive work being precomputed.

Comment: @Kevin - how do you precompute the hash for a string you don't know yet? That's why hash precomputation is relatively rare. Hash caching means you only hash each string once, but even that's pointless if each search is for a newly input/derived string anyway. Either way, sure a different algorithm has different costs, but your algorithm isn't what anyone was discussing - the original point about the cost of hash computation was in the answer which I didn't write - and it still has nothing to do with whether hash functions are cryptographic strength or not.

Comment: @Steve314: I don't understand.  You're constructing a string whose value you don't know?  In languages I'm familiar with (other than C), strings are immutable.

Comment: @Kevin - no, when you compute or input a new string you don't know the hash for that string until you pay the cost of computing it. That string may have already been inserted into the hash table, but you don't know that without finding it in the hash table - so to get the hash from the table you need to search so you need to already know the hash first.

Comment: @Steve314: That's why you compute the hash when you construct *the string*, not the hash table.  Constructing the string is already linear in string length.

Comment: @Kevin - If you're talking about interned strings, that isn't magic, it needs an implementation. Lets assume the string "Hello" is already in that interned string table. When you compute "He"+"llo" the way you get the same interned instance of "Hello" is by looking it up in the table. If the table is a hash table, first you compute the hash of "Hello", then you find the entry in the hash table. No point getting the hash from the table - you already had to compute that to find it.

Comment: @Kevin - computing a string is not necessarily linear in the string length. Concatenating a constant number of additional characters is O(1), for example, providing there's enough space to grow the string - very common in C++, and particularly relevant when dealing with some amortization scheme. For some simple hash computations you could compute the new hash from the old one in O(1) time, but this is a special case. You don't just assume a special case - if you're discussing a special case that should be stated up front.

Comment: @Kevin - also, if you compute the hash for *every* string on construction irrespective of whether you intend to search for it, constructing a string can easily become O(n^2) - that's budgeting for all the substrings you hash but never use those hashes, e.g. if you build your string by repeated concatenation of a single character. Of course you could claim building the string itself is O(n^2), but could easily be wrong - in C++ for example you'd get O(n) because memory is grown when needed by constant *factors*, not by adding a constant amount, so each iteration amortized O(1).

Comment: @Steve: Python actually does this, and has all the problems you describe.

Answer (score 25):

Matrix multiplication. The naïve O(n^3) algorithm is often used in practice as faster than Strassen's O(n^2.8) for small-ish matrices; and Strassen's is used instead of the O(n^2.3) Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm for larger matrices.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication

Comment: Coppersmith-Winograd is NEVER used. Implementing it would be a horrid task in itself and the constant is so bad it would be unfeasible even for modern scientific matrix problems.

Answer (score 24):

A simple example is the difference between various sorting algorithms. Mergesort, Heapsort, and some others are *O(n log n)*. Quicksort is *O(n^2)* worst case. But often Quicksort is faster, and in fact it performs on average like *O(n log n)*. [More info](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/sort.html).

Another example is the generation of a single Fibonacci number. The iterative algorithm is *O(n)*, whereas the matrix-based algorithm is *O(log n)*. Still, for the first couple of thousand Fibonacci numbers, the iterative algorithm is probably faster. This also depends on the implementation of course!

Algorithms with a better asymptotic performance may contain costly operations that are not necessary with an algorithm with worse performance but simpler operations. In the end, the *O*-notation only tells us something about performance when the argument it operates on increases dramatically (approaches infinity).

Comment: This is a great explanation of Big-O, but fails to address the meat of the question, which is for specific cases where an O(n) algorithm will be faster than an O(1).

Comment: The Fibonacci number one is slightly off. The output size is exponential in the input size, so it's a difference between O(lg n * e^n) vs O(lg lg n * e^n).

Comment: Addendum: at best. The matrix-based algorithm does multiplication with numbers on the order of 1.5^n, so O(lg lg n * n e^n) might be the best bound provable.

Comment: Quicksort is normally described as O(n log n) expected performance anyway - the worst case is pretty unlikely for random inputs, and building some randomness into a prepass or into the pivot selection means the worst case overall is very unlikely for significant input sizes. The worst-case is less relevant than the fact that quicksort is (1) very simple, and (2) very cache-friendly, both of which lead to significantly better constant factors than in many other sorting algorithms.

Comment: (2) is precisely the sort of external consideration that must be taken into account when looking at big-O performance.  Algorithmically, Mergesort should *always* outperform Quicksort, but resource usage and cache locality generally reverse their real-world performance positions.

Answer (score 18):

*Note:
Please read the comments by @back2dos below and other gurus, as they are in fact more helpful than what I have written - Thanks for all contributors.*

I think from the chart below (taken from: [Big O notation](http://apelbaum.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/big-o/), search for "The Pessimistic Nature of Algorithms:"), you can see that O(log n) is not *always* better than say, O(n).
So, I guess your argument is valid.

[image: Pic-1]

Comment: The question wanted specific real world examples of algorithms. This does not have any as it stands.

Comment: You can see nothing on that graph, that would answer the question. It is misleading. This graph merely plots the functions `y = 1`, `y = log x`, and so on and the intersection of `y = 1` and `y = x` is actually the point `(1,1)`. If this really were correct, than it would tell you, that algorithms of higher complexity can be faster for 0 to 2 entries, which is something people hardly would care for. What the graph completely fails to take into account (and what the perceivable performance difference in question comes from) is constant factors.

Comment: @Samuel Walker, thanks for the comment. The link provided (Link-1) has some examples of algorithms per category.

Comment: @back2dos: The graph on it's own does not answer the question, but can be used to answer it. The shape of each displayed function is the same for any scale and constant factor. With this the graph shows that given combination of functions, there is a range of inputs for which one is smaller and a range of inputs for which the other is.

Comment: @Caleb, it's not plotting `y=n^2, y=n^3...`, it's plotting examples of `y=O(n^2), y=O(n^3)...`. What is the complexity of an algorithm that does `n^3 + 2n^2` comparisons? Isn't it `O(n^3)`?

Comment: @dan_waterworth, you're right, I'll concede that point and remove that comment. Nevertheless, the answer is incorrect or misleading in two respects: 1) The whole point of Big-O is that it gives an upper bound on complexity; it's only meaningful for large n because we explicitly toss out smaller terms which are overwhelmed by the largest term as n grows. 2) The point of the question is to find examples of two algorithms where the one with the higher Big-O bound outperforms one with a lower bound. This answer fails because it doesn't give any such examples.

Comment: @Caleb, now we are in agreement.

Comment: ln(n) < n for all n > 0.  That graph is misleading and worse than useless.

Comment: The problems with this: 1: Labels are asymptotic but graph is real time. This isn't clearly explained. If you have two graphs, that fixes. Use a plotter and put in the formulas in the O. 2: Data input is float not natural numbers. Can be tolerable though. 3: Scale not clear (actually it kind of is with O(n) being 45 degs).

Comment: @jgmjgm, there is a room for improvement.

Answer (score 11):

For practical values of `n`, yes. This comes up a lot in CS theory. Often there is a complicated algorithm that has technically better big-Oh performance, but the constant factors are so large as to make it impracticaly.

I once had my computational geometry professor describe an algorithm for triangulating a polygon in linear time, but he finished with "very complicated. I don't think anyone's actually implemented it" (!!).

Also, fibonacci heaps have better characteristics than normal heaps, but are not very popular because they don't perform as well [in practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504823/has-anyone-actually-implemented-a-fibonacci-heap-efficiently) as regular heaps. This can cascade to other algorithms that use heaps - for instance, Dijkstra's shortest-paths is mathematically faster with a fibonacci heap, but usually not in practice.

Comment: It's faster for huge graphs on the order of 100,000 or so vertices.

Comment: Fibonacci heaps were my first (actually, second) thought as well.

Answer (score 10):

Compare inserting into a linked list and inserting into a resizable array.

The amount of data has to be fairly large for the linked list O(1) insertion to be worthwhile.

A linked list has extra overhead for next pointers and dereferences. A resizable array has to copy data around. That copying is O(n), but in practice very fast.

Comment: A resizable array is doubled in size each time it fills, so the average cost of resizing per insertion is O(1).

Comment: @kevincline, yes but the O(n) comes from having to move all of the elements after the insertion point forward. Allocation is amortized O(1) time. My point is that that movement is still very fast, so in practice is usually beats linked lists.

Comment: The reason contiguous arrays are so fast in comparison to linked lists is due to processor caching. Traversing a linked list will cause a cache miss for every element. To get the best of both worlds you should use an [unrolled linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrolled_linked_list).

Comment: Resizable arrays don't always copy. It depends on what it's running on and if there's anything in the way. Same for the doubling size, implementation specific. The roll over roll over thing though is a problem. Linked lists are usually best for queues of unknown size though rotary buffers give queues a run for their money. In other cases linked lists are useful because allocation or expansion simply isn't going to let you have contiguous stuff all the time so you'll need a pointer anyway.

Comment: @jgmjgm, if you insert into the middle of a resizable array, its absolutely does copy the elements after that.

Answer (score 8):

The Big-Oh notation is used to describe a function's growth-rate, so it is possible that an O(1) algorithm will be faster, but only up to a certain point (the constant factor).

Common notations:

O(1) - The number of iterations (sometimes you can refer to this as user-time spent by the function) is not dependent on the size of the input, and is in fact constant.

O(n) - The number of iterations grows in a **linear** proportion to the size of the input. Meaning - if the algorithm iterates through any input N, 2 * N times, it is still considered O(n).

O(n^2) (quadratic) - The number of iterations is the input size squared.

Comment: To add an example to an otherwise excellent answer: an O(1) method may take 37 years per call, whereas an O(n) method may take 16*n microseconds per call.  Which is faster?

Comment: I completely fail to see how this answers the question.

Comment: I understand big-O. This does not address the actual question, which is specific examples of functions where algorithms with a lower big-O are outperformed by those with a higher big-O.

Comment: When you put the question in the form "Are there examples ...", someone is inevitably going to answer "Yes." without giving any.

Comment: @rakslice: Maybe so. However this site demands explanation (or better yet proof) of any statements you make. Now the best way to proof, that there are such examples is to give one ;)

Comment: @back2dos I agree, I see now how my post could have been improved. When I posted it, I assumed that I depicted the obvious possibility the OP asks about, but failing to provide an example probably only helped those who already understood the matter in hand. I'll take it into consideration from now on. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Regex libraries are usually implemented to do backtracking which has worst case exponential time rather than DFA generation which has a complexity of `O(nm)`.

Naive backtracking can be a better performer when the input stays on the fast path or fails without the need to backtrack excessively.

(Although this decision isn't just performance based, it's also to allow back references.)

Comment: I think it's also partly historical--the algorithm for turning a regular expression into a DFA was patented when some of the earlier tools (sed and grep, I guess) were being developed. Of course I heard this from my compilers professor who wasn't entirely sure, so this is a third-hand account.

Answer (score 5):

An `O(1)` algorithm:

```
def constant_time_algorithm
  one_million = 1000 * 1000
  sleep(one_million) # seconds
end
```

An `O(n)` algorithm:

```
def linear_time_algorithm(n)
  sleep(n) # seconds
end
```

Clearly, for any value of `n` where `n < one_million`, the `O(n)` algorithm given in the example will be *faster* than the `O(1)` algorithm.

While this example is a bit facetious, it is equivalent in spirit to the following example:

```
def constant_time_algorithm
  do_a_truckload_of_work_that_takes_forever_and_a_day
end

def linear_time_algorithm(n)
  i = 0
  while i < n
    i += 1
    do_a_minute_amount_of_work_that_takes_nanoseconds
  end
end
```

You *must* know the constants and coefficients in your `O` expression, and you *must* know the expected range of `n`, in order to determine *a priori* which algorithm will end up being faster.

Otherwise, you *must* benchmark the two algorithms with values of `n` in the expected range in order to determine *a posteriori* which algorithm ended up being faster.

Answer (score 4):

Sorting:

Insertion sort is O(n^2) but outperforms others O(n*log(n)) sorting algorithms for small number of elements.

This is the reason why most sort implementations use a combination of two algorithms. E.g. use merge sort to break down large arrays until they reach a array certain size, then use insertion sort to sort the smaller units and merge them again with merge sort.

See [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) the current default implementation of Python and Java 7 sorting that use this technique.

Answer (score 4):

The [unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29) algorithm used in practice is exponential in the worst case, for some pathological inputs.

There is a [polynomial unification algorithm](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.96.6119), but it is too slow in practice.

Answer (score 3):

Bubblesort in memory can outperform quicksort when the program is being swapped to disk or need to read every item from disk when comparing.

This should be an example he can relate to.

Comment: Doesn't the quoted complexities on quicksort and bubblesort assume O(1) random memory access? If this is no longer the case, wouldn't quicksorts complexity need to be reexamined?

Comment: @ViktorDahl, the item access time is _not_ part of what is traditionally being measured in sort algorithm complexities so "O(1)" is not the right choice of words here.  Use "constant time" instead.  PHK wrote an article a while back about sort algorithms knowing that some items are more expensive to retreive than others (virtual memory) - http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1814327 - you might find it interesting.

Comment: I see my mistake now. One usually measures the number of  comparisons, and of course they are not affected by the speed of the storage medium. Also, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

Often the more advanced algorithms assume a certain amount of (expensive) setup. If you only need to run it once, you might be better off with the brute-force method.

For example: binary search and hash table lookup are both much faster *per lookup* then a linear search, but they require you to sort the list or build the hash table, respectively.

The sort will cost you N log(N) and the hash table will cost at least N. Now if you are going to be doing hundreds or thousands of lookups, that is still an amortized savings. But if you only need to do one or two lookups, it might just make sense to just do the linear search and save the startup cost.

Answer (score 1):

Decryption is often 0(1). For example the key space for DES is 2^56, so decryption of any message is a constant time operation. Its just that you have a factor of 2^56 in there so its a really big constant.

Comment: Isn't decryption of a message O(*n*), where *n* is proportional to the size of the message? As long as you have the correct key, the size of the key doesn't even enter into consideration; some algorithms have minimal or no key setup/expansion processes (DES, RSA - note that key generation may still be a complex task, but that has nothing to do with key expansion) whereas others are extremely complex (Blowfish comes to mind), but once it's done, the time to do the actual work is proportional to the size of the message, hence O(n).

Comment: You probably mean cryptananalysis rather than decryption?

Comment: Well, yes, there are any number of things that you can take to be constant and declare an algorithm to be O(1). [sorting implicitly assumes the elements take a constant amount of time to compare, for example, or any math with non-bignum numbers]

Answer (score 1):

Different implementations of sets spring to my mind. One of the most naive is implementing it over a vector, which means `remove` as well as `contains` and therefore also `add` all take O(N).
An alternative is to implement it over some general purpose hash, which maps input hashes to input values. Such a set implementation performs with O(1) for `add`, `contains` and `remove`.

If we assume N is about 10 or so, then the first implementation is probably faster. All it has to do to find an element is to compare 10 values to one.
The other implementation will have to start all sorts of clever transformations, which can be a lot more expensive, than making 10 comparisons. With all the overhead, you might even have cache misses and then it really doesn't matter how fast your solution is in theory.

This doesn't mean, that the worst implementation you can think of will outperform a decent one, if N is small enough. It simply means for sufficiently small N, that a naive implementation, with low footprint and overhead can actually require less instructions and cause less cache misses than an implementation that puts scaleability first, and will therefore be faster.

You can't really know how fast anything is in a real world scenario, until you put it into one and simply measure it. Often results are surprising (at least to me).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for suitably small N.  There will always be a N, above which you will always have the ordering O(1) < O(lg N) < O(N) < O(N log N) < O(N^c) < O(c^N) (where O(1) < O(lg N) means that at an O(1) algorithm will take fewer operations when N is suitably large and c is a some fixed constant that is greater than 1).

Say a particular O(1) algorithm takes exactly f(N) = 10^100 (a googol) operations and an O(N) algorithm takes exactly g(N) = 2 N + 5 operations.  The O(N) algorithm will give greater performance until you N is roughly a googol (actually when N > (10^100 - 5)/2), so if you only expected N to be in the range of 1000 to a billion you would suffer a major penalty using the O(1) algorithm.

Or for a realistic comparison, say you are multiplying n-digit numbers together.  The [Karatsuba algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) is at most 3 n^(lg 3) operations (that is roughly O(n^1.585) ) while the [Schönhage–Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm) is O(N log N log log N) which is a [faster order](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B%28N%20Log%5BN%5D%20Log%5BLog%5BN%5D%5D%29/N%5E1.585,%20N%20-%3E%20Infinity%5D), but to quote wikipedia:

> In practice the Schönhage–Strassen algorithm starts to outperform
>   older methods such as Karatsuba and Toom–Cook multiplication for
>   numbers beyond 2^2^15 to 2^2^17 (10,000 to 40,000 decimal
>   digits).[4][5][6]

So if you are multiplying 500 digit numbers together, it doesn't make sense to use the algorithm that's "faster" by big O arguments.

EDIT: You can find determine f(N) compared g(N), by taking the limit N->infinity of f(N)/g(N).  If the limit is 0 then f(N) < g(N), if the limit is infinity then f(N) > g(N), and if the limit is some other constant then f(N) ~ g(N) in terms of big O notation.

Answer (score 1):

The simplex method for [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) can be exponential in the worst case, while relatively new interior point algorithms can be polynomial.

However, in practice, the exponential worst case for the simplex method doesn't come up -- the simplex method is fast and reliable, while early interior point algorithms were far too slow to be competitive.  (There are now more modern interior point algorithms which *are* competitive -- but the simplex method is, too...)

Answer (score 0):

Ukkonen's algorithm for building [suffix tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) is O(n log n).  It has the advantage of being "on-line" - that is, you can incrementally append more text.

Recently, other *more complex* algorithms have claimed to be faster in practice, largely because their memory access has higher locality, thus improving processor cache utilization and avoiding CPU pipeline stalls.  See, e.g., [this survey](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CF8QFjAI&url=http://www.edbt.org/Proceedings/2010-Lausanne/edbt/papers/p0240-Tsirogiannis.pdf&rct=j&q=suffix%20trie%20faster%20than%20Ukkonen&ei=aTiPTu2FFKX40gGYuewc&usg=AFQjCNGdWWUCx9L65XrYOHstiJLuySrMQA&sig2=X8sAWsJa1KcF42MPJjbDNQ&cad=rja), which claims that 70-80% of processing time is spent waiting for memory, and [this paper](http://books.google.com/books?id=QqD8ykOYihcC&lpg=PA34&ots=H0i8DizVgk&dq=suffix%20trie%20algorithm%20locality%20wotd&pg=PA31#v=onepage&q&f=false) describing the "wotd" algorithm.

Suffix tries are important in genetics (for matching gene sequences) and, somewhat less importantly, in the implementation of Scrabble dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

There's always [the fastest and shortest algorithm for any well-defined problem](http://www.hutter1.net/ai/pfastprg.htm). It's only purely theoretically the (asymptotically) fastest algorithm though.

Given any description of a problem **P** and an instance for that problem **I**, it enumerates all possible algorithms **A** and proofs **Pr**, checking for each such pair whether **Pr** is a valid proof that **A** is the asymptotically fastest algorithm for **P**. If it finds such a proof, it then executes **A** on **I**.

Searching for this problem-proof pair has complexity O(1) (for a fixed problem **P**), so you always use the asymptotically fastest algorithm for the problem. However, since this constant is so unspeakably enormous in nearly all cases, this method is completely useless in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Many languages/frameworks use naive pattern matching to match strings instead of [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). We look for string like Tom, New York rather than ababaabababababaababababababab.